# print database rows to an array to use with javascript for filtering

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I'm trying to use php to run a sql select statement to pull data from a database and then only output one column(username) to an array that I can then use to filter using a JS script. Similar to how facebook/twitter does their real time searching of contacts when you start typing someone's name in. I keep getting an error though in php when I try to pull the username column and set it to an array and output that:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$contact = mysql_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['contact']);
$sql = "select * from users";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      printf($row["username"]);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Comment: @bitfiddler nothing get's returned, it's completely blank...if i comment out the ($row ...){...} section and just put in a simple echo'result'; it get's printed but other wise nothing gets returned...

Comment: apparently i was missing while before the ($row)...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It would help to know what the exact error PHP is giving you is. But from a cursory look on your code I believe you are missing a `while` keyword.

```
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      printf($row["username"]);
    }
```

Comment: @GregBorbonus, this isn't my question though so it's up to DRE .